How to get info about Bluetooth output device latency in Python
I've been making a Python media player, but the audio and video de-synced when using a Bluetooth speaker, and I've been wondering how to get the Bluetooth latency using Python.
I am using a MacOS device, so the PyBluez module won't work.
I tried using SimplePyBLE but when I use the module, it always gives me an exit code -9 error.
I've also attempted to use blueutil with subprocess but I don't think it has the capability to get the latency of the bluetooth device.
If anyone's wondering, I use PyQt6.QtMultimedia MediaPlayer for audio and video.
Is there any tool for MacOS Monterey 12.7.5 that I can use to get the latency of a Bluetooth device?

I don't know if macOS provides an API to get that in CoreBluetooth, but, in general, the only way to accurately get latency in bluetooth is to measure it. Still, it won't always be consistent, as it may depend on many aspects (even the same device and setup may give different results based on various conditions).

@musicamante How do platforms such as YouTube handle Bluetooth latency? Do they measure each Bluetooth device?

The website has absolutely no knowledge about the playback device of the computer. At the very best, they can query the current audio latency, assuming that the underlying audio system provides it. This means that you cannot directly query a bluetooth device about its latency (which, as said, doesn't only depend on the device), you may eventually get it in real time, and, again, assuming that the audio backend allows to get it. Then, you still have a major problem: QMediaPlayer doesn't currently provide direct means to change A/V offset, meaning that AFAIK the only way to achieve it is by »

» completely manage audio and video, possibly passing through a QAbstractVideoSurface in order to properly sync the audio buffer to the video output and actual rendering, but doing this in Python is discouraged, as Python will introduce a huge bottleneck in processing due to the abstraction layer used for the binding. You may try it, but there's no guarantee that it will work reliably. In fact, it could even be worse.
